# Google Play Filtering out Tablets with SIM

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, filtering, tablet

This is my manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="19" android:minSdkVersion="9"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS"> </uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"> </uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"> </uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"> </uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> </uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"> </uses-permission>

<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING"/>
```

One of the users reported that they cannot install the app on their Android 4.0.3 Medion Lifetab tablet even though it has a SIM card slot. Google Play says that "the app is incompatible with the device" and that it is "Designed for phones".


My thought is that this has something to do with SMS permissions, which make the telephony `<uses-feature>` required, however, this tablet does have the telephony feature, then why is not compatible?

Comment: Just because it has a SIM doesn't mean it can send or receive SMS-  it could be a data only SIM.  I think that's likely the problem.  But I can't be certain, not having such a device.

Comment: @GabeSechan According to them they can send and receive SMS messages with this SIM.

Comment: However, that does not mean that the device is properly configured for third-party SMS clients. The built-in SMS client might work where third-party ones do not.

Comment: @CommonsWare You were right. After further investigation, it turns out that the carrier had its own SMS system built in the firmware of the tablet. Messages were being sent over the tablet's internet connection instead of Android's default SMS system. All of this completely transparent to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, it turns out that the carrier had its own SMS system built in the firmware of the tablet. Messages were being sent over the tablet's internet connection instead of Android's default SMS system. All of this completely transparent to the user.